# Display multiple images in a grid using subplot()

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am trying to display 30 images in a 6 x 5 grid using `plt.subplot()` I would also like to label each individual plot with the value of j. However when I try run my code in a jupyter notebook I get this output(for some reson stack won't let me add the image so here is link to img of output):
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhqST.png)

My code:

```
plt.figure()
f, axarr = plt.subplots(5,6) 

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(6):
        axarr[j].imshow(vectors[i][j])
        axarr[j].title(j)
```

The `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imshow'` points to the line:

`axarr[j].imshow(vectors[i][j])`

How can I get the output to contain nicely spaced out images in a 6 x 5 grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axarr` is a 2D array of axes, so `axarr[j]` is a 1D numpy array (of axes).

Try:

```
plt.figure()
f, axarr = plt.subplots(5,6) 

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(6):
        axarr[i,j].imshow(vectors[i][j])
        axarr[i,j].set_title(j)
```

Comment: That sort of helped, but now I get a 'Text' object is not callable error, for the title line

Comment: @ArtemisCode7 updated, it should be `set_title` not `title`.